# Connected Services Serialization Exception System.InvalidOperationException: The type was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I generated a client and all connected classes for an external SOAP web service by using the "Connected Services" feature of Rider / Visual Studio which generates the client code by referencing a WSDL file. Hence I am a bloody beginner regarding .NET and C#, I hope for help here.

The problem is, that in the generated code there is a property that has the wrong type.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
public partial class B2BRequest
{
    private B2BParameter[] parameterField;
    private object payloadField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("parameter", Order=0)]
    public B2BParameter[] parameter
    {
        get { return this.parameterField; }
        set { this.parameterField = value; }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public object payload
    {
        get { return this.payloadField; }
        set { this.payloadField = value; }
    }
}
```

In my own code I created classes for an hierarchical XML structure, that should be assigned to the payload property like that:

```
var task = new Task
    {
        PropertyA= "Test",
        Subnode = new Subnodeclass
        {
            PropertyA = 1,
            PropertyB = 2,
        }
    };

    var b2BRequest = new B2BRequest
    {
        parameter = new[]
        {
            [...]
        },
        payload = task // here it is assigned
    };
```

The problem is, that the generated client uses some kind of xml serialization that does not accept payload of type Task, hence it is defined as type object.

I get an exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: The type XYZ.Task was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically

I can not add `XmlInclude` to the base class, hence it could be regenerated every time. Neither can I modify the `XmlSerializer` the generated client uses internally.

I've also tried to override the property by crating a partial class extension in my own namespace. But this doesn't seem to work with "Connected Services".

Can anyone give me a hint, how to change the declaration of the property to my task class type or how to cast my `Task` class instance to object properly?

The `Task` class is already extending `object`:

```
public class Task : object
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement(Order = 0)]
    public String? PropertyA { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    public Subnodeclass? Subnode { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I've tried to use a MetaType attribute to add an additional XmlElementAttribute declaration. But my class is still not recognized as object type during request serialization.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(B2BRequestMeta))]
public partial class B2BRequest
{
    internal sealed class B2BRequestMeta
    {
        private object payloadField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement(typeof(Task), Order = 1)]
        public object payload;

    }

}
```

Comment: I think this example can help you:[example](https://www.ozkary.com/2012/11/the-type-was-not-expected-use.html#:~:text=Use%20the%20XmlInclude%20or%20SoapInclude%20attribute%20to%20specify,the%20property%20and%20use%20Account%20instead%20of%20object).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found this article too. Unfortunately I can't use another XmlSerializer constructor hence I'm using an referenced Service, which does the serialization process somehow internally. I only can  use the generated client and give it a B2BRequest object as shown above, which is also a generated class. I can't get to the code, where the serialization happens.  I have the hope, that I somehow can use the partial nature of the generated class, to tell the serializer to accept my Class for the object property as well.

Comment: Or can I change the serialization behavior of a connected / referenced Service somehow? Perhaps with an MetadataType attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it that way, that I use an XML string for the property Payload now. This is an accepted an compatible object type.

I implemented this method, that creates a xml string.

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace MyNiceNamespace.Helper;

/// <summary>
/// Collection of string helper methods
/// </summary>
public static class StringUtils {
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an object to an xml string via XmlSerializer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serializableObject">Any serializable object</param>
    /// <param name="omitXmlDeclaration">whether to include the xml declaration in return string or not (default false)</param>
    /// <param name="types">Type array of types that are not strictly checked during serialisation.
    /// F.e. Classes that are used for object typed properties</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ObjectToXmlString<T>(T serializableObject, bool omitXmlDeclaration = false,
        Type[]? types = null)
    {
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            OmitXmlDeclaration = omitXmlDeclaration
        };

        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), types);

        using var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, xmlWriterSettings);

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, serializableObject);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

And in the example above I use the method StringUtils.ObjectToXmlString and assign the result to the object property.

```
var task = new Task
{
    PropertyA= "Test",
    Subnode = new Subnodeclass
    {
        PropertyA = 1,
        PropertyB = 2,
    }
};

var taskXml = StringUtils.ObjectToXmlString(task, true);

var b2BRequest = new B2BRequest
{
    parameter = new[]
    {
        [...]
    },
    payload = taskXml // here it is assigned as string object now
};
```

This works great. Nevertheless I would like to know, if there is a better - object-oriented - way to solve it (manipulate partial class or creating an object based type that is accepted by serializer).